# C# code shows error in visual studio 2015 but not 2013

Tags: c#

I've got a c# project that was coded in Visual Studio 2010. The code runs without any errors. If I open the project in Visual Studio 2015 (Community Edition) it shows error any idea.

```
UpdateControls(false);
UpdateControls(true);
```

Project code in age:

[image]

Comment: It hasn't upgraded/copied correctly. You are missing at least 2 functions.

Comment: Never post code or error messages in images here. Images should only be used for things that cannot possibly be demonstrated any other way. Your code editor has the ability to copy/paste text, so you should use it. For a list of the many reasons you should not use images, see [this Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576). Your question also makes no sense; your title says *shows error in 2015, but not 2013*, but your text says *coded in Visual Studio 2010*. Which two of those three versions are you actually having difficulties with?

Answer (score 1):

As your error message explicitly states :

> The name 'UpdateControls' does not exist in the current context.

If you manually performed this migration, it's likely that you simply neglected to copy over your `UpdateControls()` method. You should consider double-checking through your updated Project to see if it is actually missing.

If it is included within the project, then ensure that it has the proper access modifiers and it is able to be accessed (i.e. in the proper namespace, etc.).